# How would I store multiple numbers in a UInt16Array or UInt32Array?

Tags: javascript, unsigned-integer

If I have one small number, that can be from 0-8, and another larger number that can be from 0-50, how would I store both of these numbers in one index of a UInt16Array or UInt32Array?

I want to be able to access both of these values and then set them again.

Comment: use bitwise operators like `<<` and `|` and `>>`  and `&` as appropriate - p.s. , there's no such thing as a `Uint36Array`

Comment: Oops. Meant UInt32Array.

Answer (score 0):

As Jaromanda said, you have to do bitwise operations. Here I am using 16bit to store final value,
leftmost bits used for storing 0-50 and rightmost bits used for 0-8.

```js
const result = new Uint16Array([0])

const H = 42
const L = 5

console.log('H: ', H, H.toString(2))
console.log('L: ', L, L.toString(2))

console.log('--------------------')
console.log('result[0] before: ', result[0], result[0].toString(2))
result[0] = H << 8
result[0] = result[0] | L
console.log('result[0] after: ', result[0], result[0].toString(2))
console.log('--------------------')

const dL = result[0] & 0x00ff
const dH = (result[0] & 0xff00) >> 8

console.log('\ndecoded H: ', dH, dH.toString(2))
console.log('decoded L: ', dL, dL.toString(2))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It feels a bit wasteful though having both numbers be able to to store up to to 255 when realistically I only need to store a bool for the second value. Is there any way I would be able to fix this?

Comment: @radio so one num ranges from 0-50 & another 0-1 ? Are you ok with using `Int8Array` (not `Uint8Array`) ? because you can store that bool value as "plus/minus". eg if `H=42` and `L=1` we can store it as `-42`, if `L=0` then just store it as `42`.

Comment: Wait thats actually a really nice idea, thank you so much!